# React don't show image in serve

Tags: javascript, reactjs, refresh

My react project in the server don't show some images.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u8AlF.png)

The console write that:

`ASGimagen.png:1 GET https://[url of my server]/autodiagnostico/cuadroanimado/ASGimagen.png 404`

If I refresh the DOM, the image appears

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/655pw.png)

THE CODE:

```
import './cuerpoindex.css';
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
import { LazyLoadImage } from "react-lazy-load-image-component";


const ASG = 'cuadroanimado/ASGimagen.png';

function Cuerpoindex() {

    return (
        <div className="CuerpoIndex">
        {/*   <div className="indexfondo "></div>*/}  
            <div>
            Herramienta de autodiagnóstico ASG para MIPYME
            <p>Índice de Adopción de Criterios ASG</p>
            <p>Mide el grado de transición de las micro, pequeñas y medianas
            empresas hacia un modelo de negocio sostenible a partir
            de la adopción de tres criterios fundamentales:
            Ambiental (A), Social (S) y de Gobernanza (G)</p>
            </div>
            <Link to='/InicioAutodiagnostico'><LazyLoadImage className='imagenASG' src={ASG} alt="logo empresa"></LazyLoadImage></Link>
            
            <div className="BotonComenzar">
            </div>
        </div>
      );
  }

export default Cuerpoindex
```

I want to show the imagen at the start. I already tried to use "Lazyload" it didn't work. That isn't a route problem, I guess is a refresh problem.

Comment: But your url returns 404, so I guess it's not because of react. Accessing the same url after a few seconds returns the image. Looks like a server issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved that, with "import", and i moved the imagen in the same carpet.

```
import ImgAsg from "./ASGimagen.png"
```

// const ASG = 'cuadroanimado/ASGimagen.png';